# mysql - dynamic query depending on multiple grouped other values

Tags: mysql

In my application there are products and a product-variant-group which has a defined set of properties which a product of this group must declare and the combination of the properties is unique across that product-variant-group.

**Example screen from amazon:**

[image]

In the image the first select menu has all values obviously. The next select menu depends on the previously selected value, and so on.

Those defined group properties have a unique priority assigned to it which in the following derived table equals the property itself.

For a given property/priority and given list of of property/priority-value pairs. I want to retrieve its possible values.
The priorities of the value pairs must be smaller then the given priority.

```
public String[] getProductVariantGroupValues(int productVariantGroupId, int priority, Map<Integer, String> prevValues);
```

An example makes it much clearer:

I have an sql statement which lists all product-variant-group properties that related products have defined:

```
+---------+----------+-------- +
| product | priority | value   |
+---------+----------+---------+
|       1 |        1 | Black   |
|       1 |        2 | 38      |
|       1 |        3 | Dots    |
|       2 |        1 | Black   |
|       2 |        2 | 38      |
|       2 |        3 | Stripes |
|       3 |        1 | Yellow  |
|       3 |        2 | 40      |
|       3 |        3 | Stripes |
+---------+----------+---------+

Other view for understanding *(priority is arbitrary just for understanding, with this view this would be trivial)*:

+---------+--------+--------+---------+
| product | value1 | value2 | value3  |
+---------+--------+--------+---------+
|       1 | Black  | 38     | Dots    |
|       2 | Black  | 38     | Stripes |
|       3 | Yellow | 40     | Stripes |
+---------+---------------------------+
```

Call the above method with `priority = 3` and prevValues = `{(1, Black), (2, 38)}` should result in following result array: **`{Dots, Stripes}`**.

*If `black` is selected for property/priority `1` and `38` is selected for property/priority `2` the only possible following values for property/priority `3` are `{Dots, Stripes}`*

**The example is simplified and an arbitrary number of properties/priority should be supported. The query must be created dynamically to support arbitrary number of lower priority values.**

*Maybe I should just use the second table appraoch with a fixed set of properties which would make the unique constraint and this query very simple.*

Comment: What's the purpose of the value in the pair? If you run it with priority = 3 and {(1,Black),(2,40)} do you get {38, Dots, Stripes}?

Comment: `{(1,Black),(2,40)}` would not return any result since `(2, 40)` is not possible since no product has the property `(1,Black)` and `(2, 40)`. I added a screen what i want to implement and added a different view on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a value for priority 1 and for priority 2 and want to get all priority 3 values that match.  The following query gets the products:

```
select product
from t
group by product
having max(case when priority = 1 and value = 'Black' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when priority = 2 and value = 40 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

To get the priority 3 values requires or a clever select statement (assuming priorities are not repeated for a product):

```
select product, max(case when priority = 3 then value end)
from t
group by product
having max(case when priority = 1 and value = 'Black' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when priority = 2 and value = 40 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

These queries are to give you an idea of how to construct the queries in your code.  The generalization should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Great thanks, this works very well. Priorities are unique for a product. Do you know why an ascending order by on value is not working?